# Angular request with multiple status

Tags: angular, typescript

How do we cleanly implement calling from api with 2 different status without repeating the code>?

I have a function which is get count which gets the total count of users with different status , the first status is ForApproval and the second status is Draft

I want to get the total count of users with status ForApproval  and Draft and add both to get the total , how do we implement that without duplicating the code below and getting the total of both at once? Thanks.

#ts code

```
 this.getCount('ForApproval');
     this.getCount('Draft');

    private getCount(item:any) {
        let status = item;
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.dealService.getCount(
          this.accountId,
          this.transaction.id,
          status
        )
          .pipe(
            finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
          )
          .subscribe({
            error: err => this.notificationService.showError(err),
            next: res => {
              this.total = res.data
            },
            complete: noop
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit weird, but you can try it:

```
import { Observer } from 'rxjs';

const observer:Observer = 
{   
   next: res => {
              this.total = res.data;

              if (this.draft) {
                 this.draft = false;
                 this.getCount('Draft')
                    .subscribe(observer);
              }

   },
   error: err => this.notificationService.showError(err),
   complete: noop
};

this.draft = true;

this.getCount('ForApproval') 
   .subscribe(observer);


private getCount(item:any) {

   let status = item;
   this.isLoading = true;
   
   return this.dealService.getCount(
          this.accountId,
          this.transaction.id,
          status
   )
   .pipe(
      finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
   );        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is using the zip operator.

```
zip(
    this.getCount('ForApproval'),
    this.getCount('Draft')
)
.subscribe(res => this.total = res[0].data + res[1].data)
```

```
private getCount(item) {
    let status = item;
    return this.dealService.getCount(
          this.accountId,
          this.transaction.id,
          status
    )
}
```

Comment: Sir , what if I want to get total , and I also want to get deals with ForApproval status separately , can I still use that function ? @Sam

Comment: Yes, zIp is returning an array with the results of the observables you pass to it. So in this case you can access both responses & set them to variables.